# How do I access resources using maven in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, opencv, filepath

I am using trying to use the facial detection part of OpenCV and I ran into a tutorial on how to do it however he assumed we were importing the OpenCV library instead of using Maven. This is his code:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);    
System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");
CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath());
```

When I run this I get an error saying it cannot find the library which makes sense because it's in Maven. How would I get the file path of the resource "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" to use here?

Comment: So what is your question actually?

Comment: @Michal How to I access "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" while using OpenCV through Maven? Where do I find it? Specifically what file path

Comment: Does this xml file exist within your project? Is it within a jar?

Comment: @JamesB I can put the XML anywhere. I would like to take it out of OpenCV but it seems that is impossible. If I place it into a folder under my project (JavaProgram/Assets/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml) how would I access it then?

Comment: are those assets zipped ? then you have to upack it to a local file first.

Comment: If you are free to put the file wherever you want, why do not you just put it somewhere into file system and use the location of that file as the path value? Or is your question more like, I have file somewhere on the classpath and would like to know the physical path?

Comment: As far as I can see your question has nothing to do with OpenCV or maven.

Comment: Have you tried putting the file in the folder <project_root>/src/main/resources?